# How to split a string composed of letters and digits

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string composed of a letter followed by digits, e.g.

```
String s = "C34M78N8X";
```

I want to split every letter with the numbers next to it so it would be:

```
{"C34" "M78" "N8" "X"} //in that order
```

Any idea about any class methods I could use from `String` or `Integer` maybe? I'm a beginner with Java, so I'm trying to learn different things. I researched everywhere and couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"how to **split** a string"* + *"any idea about any class **methods** i could use **from String**"* --- How about the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method? --- I frankly don't know how it's possible to research how to split a string in Java and not find that method.

Comment: *"I therefore can't specify the regex"* Why not? That's exactly what regex is good at. Or did you mean that ***you*** can't, because you don't know regex well enough? If so, then you phrased the question wrong. --- *"I researched everywhere and couldn't find **anything**"* Incorrect. You found the `split()` method, but you rejected it, which is too bad, since it's what you need.

Comment: I did say "eg" to indicate that this was just an example. I wanted a code that will work with any string I input, not this one specifically. With String.split() you have to specify a regular expression, but every string I input will have different letters and numbers, and I want every letter and its following numbers to be split. I therefore can't specify the regex in the String.split() method. Sorry I should've made that clearer.

Comment: Listen, I'm a beginner. I'm sorry if my research didn't show me how to use the split method the way you suggested. It was an innocent question, it's really not that big of an issue. Thanks for the help anyway. I even got a negative vote, so now I can't post questions, I hope that brings you some peace of mind

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025853/how-to-split-a-string-comprised-of-letters-and-ints/67025976#comment118475796_67025976)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "C34M78N8X";
        String[] arr = s.split("(?=\\p{L})");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[C34, M78, N8, X]
```

`\p{L}` [matches a letter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `(?=(regex))` is used for [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

More explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JPKeVS/1):

[image]

### Original answer:

Using the regex, `\w(?:\d+)?`, you can get the matches using the Java regex API.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getTokens("C34M78N8X"));

    }

    static List<String> getTokens(String textString) {
        return Pattern
                .compile("\\w(?:\\d+)?")
                .matcher(textString)
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[C34, M78, N8, X]
```

**Non-`Stream` solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(getTokens("C34M78N8X"));

    }

    static List<String> getTokens(String textString) {
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w(?:\\d+)?").matcher(textString);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matches.add(matcher.group());
        }

        return matches;
    }
}
```

Learn more about Java RegEx API at **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)**

**Explanation of the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rzWvzA/1):**

[image]

Comment: Given the sample inputs, a simple `split("(?=\\p{L})")` (split before letter) would do the trick too, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to split between and two non-digit characters.

You can do that with any two of the following:

- `?!\\d)` zero width negative look-ahead for a digit
- `(?=\\D)`  zero width positive look-ahead for a non-digit

So using `(?!\\d)(?=\\D)` the regular expression simply says, "*Match the area where you see a non-digit followed by a non-digit.*"

```
String[] data = { "ABCDEF","A12345","A1B2C3D4","AX3YM67", "A1233BB1233", "A3D456F6D" };
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : data) {
    String[] st = str.split("(?!\\d)(?=\\D)");
    lists.add(Arrays.asList(st));
}

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(data[i] + " --> " +  lists.get(i));
}
```

prints

```
ABCDEF --> [A, B, C, D, E, F]
A12345 --> [A12345]
A1B2C3D4 --> [A1, B2, C3, D4]
AX3YM67 --> [A, X3, Y, M67]
A1233BB1233 --> [A1233, B, B1233]
A3D456F6D --> [A3, D456, F6, D]
```